# Using Linq select list inside list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Using LINQ how to select from a List within a List

```
public class Model
{
    public string application { get; set; }

    public List<Users> users { get; set; }
}

public class Users
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string surname { get; set; }
}

List<Model> list = new List<Model>();
```

I need to select list where application = "applicationame" and users where surname = "surname" into one list.

Comment: What is the output you want? A list of _Model_? A list of _User_?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to filter the models by `applicationname` and the remaining models by `surname`:

```
List<Model> newList = list.Where(m => m.application == "applicationname")
    .Select(m => new Model { 
        application = m.application, 
        users = m.users.Where(u => u.surname == "surname").ToList() 
    }).ToList();
```

As you can see, it needs to create new models and user-lists, hence it is not the most efficient way.

If you instead don't want to filter the list of users but filter the models by users with at least one user with a given username, use `Any`:

```
List<Model> newList = list
    .Where(m => m.application == "applicationname"
            &&  m.users.Any(u => u.surname == "surname"))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 12):

You have to use the [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) extension method or its equivalent syntax in pure LINQ.

```
(from model in list
 where model.application == "applicationname"
 from user in model.users
 where user.surname == "surname"
 select new { user, model }).ToList();
```

Comment: Like your use of anonymous classes.

Answer (score 3):

```
list.Where(m => m.application == "applicationName" && 
           m.users.Any(u => u.surname=="surname"));
```

if you want to *filter* users as TimSchmelter commented, you can use

```
list.Where(m => m.application == "applicationName")
    .Select(m => new Model
    {
        application = m.application,
        users = m.users.Where(u => u.surname=="surname").ToList()
    });
```

Comment: He needs to select _users where surname = "surname"_, not models which contain at least one  user with surname="surname". Hence i think he wants to filter the users in each filtered model.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The kewword is: `i think he wants ...`.

Comment: Yes, i'm not sure, but that's what OP has said. Otherwise he should have said that he wants _models with application = "applicationame" which contains a user with surname = "surname"_.

Answer (score -1):

After my previous answer disaster, I'm going to try something else.

```
List<Model> usrList  = 
(list.Where(n => n.application == "applicationame").ToList());
usrList.ForEach(n => n.users.RemoveAll(n => n.surname != "surname"));
```

Comment: Inside your foreach "n" is referencing to the objects in the main data source (on memory), so you are modifying objects in the source list!

Comment: Plus - ForEach returns void which you assume it returns IEnumerable<Model>.