# List inside List - Filter

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I need to get all the channels where user is same as current user

- allChannels is list of Channel
- Users is an array in each channel

  ```
  allChannels.Select(channel => new Channel 
  { 
     users = channel.Users.Where(user => user.userId == currentUserId).ToArray()
  }).ToList();
  ```

This always return all the channels and is not filtering

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the `Users` contains any user with the given id:

```
allChannels.Where(c => c.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == currentUserId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663971/using-linq-select-list-inside-list    How this works? Am I missing anything here? I believe the surname there is same as userId here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534631(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
var result = allChannels.SelectMany(x => x.Users,
                         (channelObj, user) => new { channelObj, user})
                        .Where(x => x.user== currentUserId)
                        .Select(x => x.channelObj);
```